# Map multiple lists(acting as values) with a single list(acting as key) to create a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
headers = ['id', 'product', 'plan']

values = [['1', 'abc', '123'],['2', 'efg', '1234'],['3', 'ijk', '890']]

data = []

for entries in values:
    data.append(dict(itertools.izip(headers, entries)))
```

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: This appears to work fine.  When I run it in Python 2 I get a list of `{'product': 'abc', 'id': '1', 'plan': '123'}` style entries.  If you're using Python 3, replace `itertools.izip` with `zip`

Comment: expected output= {["id":'1','product':'abc','plan':'123'],["id":'2','product':'efg','plan':'1234'],["id":'3','product':'ijk','plan':'890']}

Comment: I need it in the expected output form. need to map keys to each values in the lists.

Comment: How can I proceed? is my approach correct?

Comment: That's not how dictionaries work. Instead you should be expecting a list of dicts. `list_of_dicts = [{k:v for k,v in zip(headers, v)} for v in values]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common pattern for this type of data abstraction is a list of dicts which easily translates to JSON - an array of objects.

```
import pprint

headers = ['id', 'product', 'plan']

values = [
    ['1', 'abc', '123'],
    ['2', 'efg', '1234'],
    ['3', 'ijk', '890'],
]

list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(headers, row)) for row in values]

pprint.pprint(list_of_dicts)
```

output

```
[{'id': '1', 'plan': '123', 'product': 'abc'},
 {'id': '2', 'plan': '1234', 'product': 'efg'},
 {'id': '3', 'plan': '890', 'product': 'ijk'}]
```

Comment: I updated the answer with a better list comprehension.